# I found a jquery image rotatation script and adding hyperlinks to the images breaks the animation

Tags: jquery, image, hyperlink, rotator

Found this great article on using jquery for image swapping:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/05/replacing-images-at-time-intervals.html

How do you suggest I hyperlink the images?

Comment: Put anchor tags around them?  You really haven't described the problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
function swapImages() {
    var $active = $('#myGallery a:has(img) > img.active');
    var $next = ($('#myGallery a:has(img.active)').next().find('img').length > 0) ? $('#myGallery a:has(img.active)').next().find('img') : $('#myGallery a:has(img):first > img');
    $active.fadeOut(function() {
        $active.removeClass('active');
        $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Learn how jquery works and fix it! Or use a plugin such as the cycle plugin - this still requires some knowledge of jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Untested but it should work...

```
function swapImages(tag){
  var element = tag||'img';
  var $active = $('#myGallery '+tag+'.active');
  var $next = ($('#myGallery '+tag+'.active').next().length > 0) ? $('#myGallery '+tag+'.active').next() : $('#myGallery '+tag+':first');
  $active.fadeOut(function(){
    $active.removeClass('active');
    $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
  });
}

  setInterval(function(){swapImages('a');}, 5000);

  // or the original usage with no links on the images
  setInterval(swapImages, 5000);
```

Just keep in mind whatever you provide as `tag` will get the class `active` so adjsut the css as nessecary.

Anyhow, this is really simple - i would also suggest doing some tutorials or reading the documentation for jQuery. You should be able to parse this script as you read it - its pretty simple :-)

Comment: This got me started.  Thanks!